# Possible to have browser bypass content type when loading CSS file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webserver

I have a web server on a device (proprietary) that serves all files as:

```
Content-Type:text/html
```

I would like to use it to host CSS and JS script files.  Is it possible to have the browser ignore the content type and load the file as CSS or JS when using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there no way you can override the content type from the file itself? E.g. if you put this in a php file the content-type should be altered:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/css') ?>
```

You probably aren't using php, but perhaps something like that is possible on your web server.

In any case you should be able to use JS-files with a text/html content-type anyway. Now stylesheets ... I guess you could load them into your html dynamically if there really is no other way.

Using jQuery because I'm lazy:

```
<style id="dynamic-css"></style>

<script>
    $('#dynamic-css').load('css/main.css');
</script>
```

Comment: one caveat with the pattern: it breaks sheet-relative paths for in-css linked assets.